# Determining whether a request came via socket or URL with Tornado

Tags: python, sockets, tornado

I have a Tornado server that listens on both an address/port, and on a socket. I create the server roughly like so (stripped down heavily):

```
from tornado import httpserver
from tornado.netutil import bind_unix_socket

server = httpserver.HTTPserver(
    request_callback=some_callback,
    io_loop=some_loop,
)
unix_socket = bind_unix_socket("mysock.sock")
server.add_socket(unix_socket)
server.listen(address="some_host", port=1234)
```

I'd like to be able to differentiate when a request is received via the socket, ie something like:

```
curl -XGET --unix-socket mysock.sock http:/ping
```

As opposed to:

```
curl http://some_address:1234/ping
```

I looked at the [HTTPServerRequest](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest) that Tornado uses when a request is received, but I'm not sure what the best way is to tell the difference between the two. I can look at `remote_ip` to see if it comes from localhost, but I don't think that's ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` is an internet-domain interface with a well-known IP address. It's not the same as a unix-domain socket, which has no IP address.

A brief look at the source suggests that the `remote_ip` attribute will contain `'0.0.0.0'` for a connection received on the unix socket.

(The `remote_ip` would presumably be `'127.0.0.1'` for a connection received via a localhost connection.)

Comment: Looks like `remote_ip` will be `0.0.0.0` for a unix socket as per `tornado.httpserver.py` in the source (https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/81ee310adcd905fbdf7c98d9fb6ef0c5a46026c2/tornado/httpserver.py#L203). Additionally, I believe the `address_family` in the `request.context` will be `AF_UNIX`.